# Creating new columns to assign value whether a column contains a word

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which contains multiple columns. I need to look if a column contains some words:

- if it contains the word "Donald" then create a new column called "Donald" and assign 1 to all the rows which contain this word, otherwise 0;
- if it contains both the word "Donald" and "Trump" then create a new column called "Donald Trump" and assign 1 to all the rows which contain both these words, otherwise 0.

Example of dataset:

```
Text                                                              Date
Donald is a common name in the US                               02/12/2020
Donald Trump is the president of the United States              05/21/2017
I have never been in the US                                     11/02/2016
```

I would need to have as follows

```
Text                                                              Date            Donald    Donald Trump
Donald is a common name in the US                               02/12/2020           1       0
Donald Trump is the president of the United States              05/21/2017           1       1
I have never been in the US                                     11/02/2016           0       0
```

I have tried the following:

```
df_donald=df_low[df_low['Text'].str.contains("donald")]
df_donald['Donald']=1
```

and

```
df_donald_trump=df_low[df_low['Text']str.contains(r'(?=.*donald)(?=.*trump)')]

df_donald_trump['Donald Trump']=1
```

then to concatenate with the original dataset, but I would prefer to do it in the same dataset.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add parameter `case=False` and for `1,0` for `True, False` using [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html):

```
m1 = df_low['Text'].str.contains("donald", case=False)
m2 = df_low['Text'].str.contains(r'(?=.*donald)(?=.*trump)', case=False)

df_low['Donald'] = m1.view('i1')
df_low['Donald Trump'] = m2.view('i1')
```

Alternative:

```
df_low['Donald'] = m1.astype('int')
df_low['Donald Trump'] = m2.astype('int')
print (df_low)
                                                Text        Date  Donald  \
0                  Donald is a common name in the US  02/12/2020       1   
1  Donald Trump is the president of the United St...  05/21/2017       1   
2                        I have never been in the US  11/02/2016       0   

   Donald Trump  
0             0  
1             1  
2             0
```

Or:

```
m1 = df_low['Text'].str.contains("donald", case=False)
m3 = df_low['Text'].str.contains('trump', case=False)

df_low['Donald'] = m1.view('i1')
df_low['Donald Trump'] = (m1 & m3).view('i1')
```

Alternative:

```
df_low['Donald'] = m1.astype('int')
df_low['Donald Trump'] = (m1 & m3).astype('int')

print (df_low)
                                                Text        Date  Donald  \
0                  Donald is a common name in the US  02/12/2020       1   
1  Donald Trump is the president of the United St...  05/21/2017       1   
2                        I have never been in the US  11/02/2016       0   

   Donald Trump  
0             0  
1             1  
2             0
```

Comment: thanks jezrael. What does i1 mean? What is the package should I need for view?

Comment: It means integer, with `0,1` like mentioned [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html)

Comment: Thanks. About view, could you please tell me what package do I need for it? I am getting this error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'view'

Comment: @LucaDiMauro - What is your pandas version? If not working use alternative, give me a sec.

Comment: my pandas' version is 1.0.3

Comment: I test it in `pandas 1.1.1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221992/discussion-between-luca-di-mauro-and-jezrael).

Comment: Thanks jezrael. Unfortunately the alternative gives me this other error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'kingreece'